# How can I "reset" my Protractor test after each individual test is run?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Im testing a gridster layout using protractor. In the first test I drag and drop my first tile into a random grid location. After testing for that first action I simply want to start my second test (drag and dropping the second tile) USING THE INITIAL DOM layout when the page first loads.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean after every spec - You can add this to your config file (under `capabilities`, where you specify the browser): `shardTestFiles: true,`

OR

If you meant after every `it` block, you can add this to your config file `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,`  -- however, this will slow down your tests a lot.

More info here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js